# Delete Specific getstream feed

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I want to delete getstream feed *(Single complete stream like `TIMELINE:200`)* by using nodejs client

```
const timeline = client.feed('TIMELINE', '200');
timeline.delete(); // this line throws error
```

> TypeError: timeline_200.feed.delete is not a function

Answer (score -1):

We don't currently have an API endpoint or SDK method to delete a feed.

Generally it's not an issue - hypothetically, let's say a user (who has some feeds) deletes/deactivates their account from your app. Whenever that user returns to your app, they won't be able to log in, but you also won't be making the requests to retrieve their feed server-side. That feed (and the associated activities) still exist somewhere, but you just won't access them from your application.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I agree, we will block the user access for this particular case. But actually it costs us to save unique records on your servers. If user is no more with us, we don't want to keep his stream.

Comment: IMHO, If we can create - we should be able to destroy. Otherwise it could cause unpredictable consequences like breaking laws of personal data and so on.

Comment: But at the same time, if we can't remove a feed which is following 10 feeds where users are posting, it costs us updates... Thing is it shouldn't as we don't care about updating this feed since the user wanted all of its data to be removed...

Comment: I'm in the same situation. When a user is deleted we want to remove their getstream feed. I am right now looking at 3+ year old code in Laravel and I can see this use to work but clearly no in the latest versions. I'm using the GetStream laravel plugin and I clearly see inthe code FeedManager::getFeed('','')->delete();

Comment: Is this still the case?